# Mongodb stats explanation

Tags: mongodb

When doing a mongotop, on my mongo inst6allation I get the following data

mydb_live.my_logs     10303ms     10302ms         1ms

So the total is 10303ms, the read is 10302ms and the write is 1ms.

Now when doing a db.system.profile.find with the profileLevel set to 2, I do not get any slow queries that may explain the 10303ms time spent in the mydb_live namespce.

Question:

Is the data reported by mongotop irrespective of the queries? i.e. does it include any background processes like index rebuilding?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple concurrent reads for a particular database - that is the total time being spent in that database for reads by all the reads that are active.  Assuming you are running with the default interval of 1 second for mongotop, there might be (for example) 5000 reads that are being serviced in ~2ms over that second.  If you are running a longer interval, the numbers would be less dramatic.

Setting the profile level to 2 will show you all operations in the profiler.  So if there are no slow queries in there, you aren't seeing any slow queries.